# Pandas read_pickle() function returns NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I'm extracting features from Tweets which I then save in a Pandas DataFrame see here:

```
for idx, tweet in tweets.iterrows():
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'assertive_verbs_count'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'assertive_verb_tf'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'factive_verbs_count'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'factive_verb_tf'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'implicative_verbs_count'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'implicative_verb_tf'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'report_verbs_count'], \
    data_frame.loc[idx, 'report_verb_tf'] = LF.bias_cues(idx, tweet)

data_frame.to_pickle('features_df' + '.pickle')
```

All features are computed correctly and no NaN values occur in the data_frame. I've checked this by printing data_frame. After this I want to load this DataFrame using pandas read_pickle() function:

```
data_frame2 = pd.read_pickle('features_df' + '.pickle')
```

When I now print this 'data_frame2' it returns NaN values in some places. For example when printing the feature 'implicative_verb_tf' it returns this:

```
print(data_frame['implicative_verb_tf'].head(10))

0     True
1      NaN
2    False
3      NaN
4     True
5      NaN
6      NaN
7    False
8    False
9      NaN
```

Does anyone know how this is possible?

Comment: Why are you pickling in the first place?

Comment: I simplified the problem but actually I'm extracting a lot of features which takes around 20 hours to compute. Afterwards I want to use these features so I can train a machine learning model and therefore I have to save these features in between.

Comment: I'm having a hard time replicating your error. What were the dtypes of the columns affected? Could you produce a minimum working example for us? And please be absolutely sure that the initial dataframe contains no NaN values by trying `data_frame.isnull().values.any()` instead of just printing it.

Comment: Can you print the same `head(10)` function before the pickling too

Comment: try pickle module itself. `import pickle; pickle.dump(dataframe, output_filename); pickle.load(output_filename)`.

Comment: Sorry guys. I found the bug, it went wrong before pickling and after I tested if there were any NaN values. In another function I accidentally replaced the values of some of these features due to wrong indexing. Thanks anyway for tips! Do I have to delete this question since it contains wrong information?